# Mathematica not honoring the distributive property of multiplication?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.2**

---

```
Reduce[
  ForAll[
     {multiplicant, summandA, summandB}, 
     Element[{multiplicant, summandA, summandB}, Reals], 
     multiplicant*summandA - multiplicant*summandB == multiplicant*(summandA - summandB)]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Duh. So obvious.

Well, it seems it's not obvious enough for *Mathematica*. See:

```
    Multiplicant[x_] := 1/((1 + x^2)*(2 + x^2))

    SummandA[x_] := 2*x*(2 + x^2)*Log[2 + x^2]

    SummandB[x_] := 2*x*(1 + x^2)*Log[1 + x^2]

    Reduce[ForAll[
        x, Element[x, Reals],
        Multiplicant[x]*SummandA[x] - Multiplicant[x]*SummandB[x] == 
        Multiplicant[x]*(SummandA[x] - SummandB[x])]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

WHAAAT...?!?!

By the law of the distribution of multiplication over addition the correct result of `Out[5]` should be `True`.

Or, the other possibility is that my brain got Shrouded in the Shadows of Shades and thus is unable to work properly.

Or, the other other possibility is that I simply cannot use Mma properly and the above sample is alimented with some kind of PEBKAC.

Could you very kindly help me figure out which one of the above three ideas is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is very peculiar behavior, which I can reproduce on 10.0.2 on a Mac.  It's especially weird since `FullSimplify[
 ExpandAll[
  Multiplicant[x]*SummandA[x] - Multiplicant[x]*SummandB[x] - 
   Multiplicant[x]*(SummandA[x] - SummandB[x])]]` yields 0 (even without the assumption that `x` is in `Reals`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a bug in `Reduce`.

It affects cases when the input contains a univariate equation `f==g` inside the `ForAll` quantifier, `f-g` is not an explicit polynomial, and `Together[f-g]` is zero.

Thank you for pointing it out.